# Putting Chromium back into Gnome Shell notifications

Tags: gnome, chromium, notification-area, desktop-background

So I'm loving Gnome Shell under 11.10 on my HP Mini 100-3000, but I've removed Chromium from the background tasks that would show on the bottom notification display.

Simple question:

How do I put it back?  I've been looking for an answer for the last few days and have come up with nothing so far.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you remove it by right clicking and choosing for it to not be displayed?

Comment: If you have found a solution to this question, please answer you own question so this can be marked as solved. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Go to chrome://chrome/settings/ in chromium
2. Scroll down to the bottom where it says Background apps.
3. Check the box underneath
4. Log out and log back in to your computer.

Hope this helps,

Leinardo